# Google Analytics Page Views not logging

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have implemented the script tag into the head of my document and I am able to log events by using the following code:

```
 ga('send', 'event', {
   eventCategory: 'Virtual Page View',
   eventAction: 'click',
   eventLabel: window.location.href
 });
```

I can access this on my GA Dashboard in REAL-TIME --> Events. So I know that my account is integrated with my application ok.

REAL-TIME --> Overview is also logging out information, for example, how many users are on the site at any given time.

However, when I go to AUDIENCE --> Overview, nothing is being registered.

I've tried logging page views like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', window.location.href);
```

But this doesn't log it here or in the realtime -> overview section. Can anyone see what I might be missing here?

Comment: window.location.href is a bit strange as page parameter - the third parameter is supposed to be a page path, not a full url. I don't think that causes your problem, but it is still worth changing. Since apparently you want the default url in any case you can simply drop the third parameter to the ga send call.

Comment: Thanks - yeah I was actually adapting this from another function, I'm just keen to get something logging, and then I can refine the params later.